# Can't get MariaDB to start..OpenSuse 15.2

Tags: opensuse, mariadb

I am logged in as root and below is what I see when I try to start the service. I have removed and reinstalled,  I have also ran mysql_install_db.  So far I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

```
law-amp3:/var/log # systemctl status mysql.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-11-09 14:02:10 CST; 14s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 7130 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper upgrade (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7117 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper install (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 09 14:01:09 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: Stale files from previous upgrade detected, cleaned them up
Nov 09 14:01:09 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: Running protected MySQL...
Nov 09 14:01:09 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: Waiting for MySQL to start
Nov 09 14:01:09 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: 2021-11-09 14:01:09 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.17-MariaDB-log) starting as process 7154 ...
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: MySQL is still dead
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: MySQL didn't start, can't continue
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 09 14:02:10 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Remove maria server, and delete /etc/my.cnf & /var/lib/mysql then reinstall. That will wipe any old databases which were there before. It seems to be failing to upgrade one or more which were still there. If you need then, them move /var/lib/mysql to a different place and reinstall. Lastly, are you using the supplied maria install files with opensuse, or are you installing from the maria web site?

Comment: I am installing from OpenSuse

Comment: @SamuelBrown the error message already gives you a hint: `Nov 09 14:01:09 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[7130]: Stale files from previous upgrade detected, cleaned them up`   Also the log files of mysql / mariadb will give you more details.

Comment: Ok I was able to get it started by following Bib's suggestions.  Appears my problem was related to the my.cnf file.  Now I am encounter another problem   When I go into the my.cnf file and add:
#datadir = /home/mysql

Answer (score 0):

The following from Bib worked for me:

Remove maria server:

- delete `/etc/my.cnf` and `/var/lib/mysql`
- then reinstall

That will wipe any old databases which were there before. It seems to be failing to upgrade one or more which were still there. If you need then, them move `/var/lib/mysql` to a different place and reinstall.

After doing this I was able to get MariaDB started.  It appears my issue was the datadir line in `my.cnf` file was causing it not to start.